# ASP .NET MVC - Change domain used by URL.Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, seo, action, actionlink

I have a website that has two domains pointing to the same content. Let's call them www.domainA.com and www.domainB.com where www.domainA.com/Page is the same as www.domainB.com/Page.

Every page on the site has a number of common navigation links (and others) that are constructed using a mixture of Url.Action and Html.ActionLink calls. The resulting urls are based on the current domain. Because www.domainA.com is the primary domain, I would like any links generated from www.domainB.com to be based on www.domainA.com.

Can this be done centrally, rather than me going around the whole site and hard-coding it?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9332671/101642) to instruct IIS to rewrite requests to my old domain.

Hope this helps others with the same requirement.

Alan

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by having custom route objects, that inherit from `System.Web.Routing.Route`.

For instance:

```
public class MultipleDomainRoute : System.Web.Routing.Route
{
    // ...

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        VirtualPathData path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);

        if (requestContext.Url.Host == "domain2.com") {
             path.VirtualPath = "http://domain1.com" + path.VirtualPath;
        }

        return path;
    }
}
```

Then in your global.asax, where you register your routes use:

```
routes.Add(new MultipleDomainRoute(/* args */));
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. This looks like what I need. However, I need to implement a constructor. The minimum constructor takes the url pattern and an IRouteHandler instance. Do I need to implement an IRouteHandler myself?

Comment: You can just redirect the constructors back to the base class. See an example here: http://coderjournal.com/2008/03/force-mvc-route-url-lowercase/.